# Not able to unmarshal xml file using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have done the following

1. Created a XML file by myself.
2. Converted it to XSD using online tool
3. Copied the generated POJOs in my project
4. And tried creating Object using JAXB unmarshaller

**Step 1: XML I created**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<corpsSymbol>
    <section sectionname="ARMOUR">
        <SIDCvalue sidcname="ArmdRegt" sidc="SFGPUCA----FING"></SIDCvalue>
        <SIDCvalue sidcname="ArmdRegtHQ" sidc="SFGPUCA---AFING"></SIDCvalue>
    </section>
    <section sectionname="ENGINEERS">
        <SIDCvalue sidcname="EngineersCompany" sidc="SFGPUCE----EING"></SIDCvalue>
        <SIDCvalue sidcname="EngineersCompanyHQ" sidc="SFGPUCE---AEING"></SIDCvalue>
    </section>
</corpsSymbol>
```

**Step 2: Converted it to XSD**

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="SIDCvalue">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
          <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="sidcname" use="optional"/>
          <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="sidc" use="optional"/>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="section">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="SIDCvalue" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="sectionname" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="corpsSymbol">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="section" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**Step 3: Following POJOs are created (Removed the comment)**

*CorpsSymbol*

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "section"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "corpsSymbol")
public class CorpsSymbol {

    protected List<Section> section;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
    protected String name;

    public List<Section> getSection() {
        if (section == null) {
            section = new ArrayList<Section>();
        }
        return this.section;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String value) {
        this.name = value;
    }

}
```

*Section*

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "sidCvalue"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "section")
public class Section {

    @XmlElement(name = "SIDCvalue")
    protected List<SIDCvalue> sidCvalue;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "sectionname")
    protected String sectionname;

    public List<SIDCvalue> getSIDCvalue() {
        if (sidCvalue == null) {
            sidCvalue = new ArrayList<SIDCvalue>();
        }
        return this.sidCvalue;
    }
    public String getSectionname() {
        return sectionname;
    }

    public void setSectionname(String value) {
        this.sectionname = value;
    }

}
```

*SIDCvalue*

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "value"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "SIDCvalue")
public class SIDCvalue {

    @XmlValue
    protected String value;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "sidcname")
    protected String sidcname;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "sidc")
    protected String sidc;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getSidcname() {
        return sidcname;
    }

    public void setSidcname(String value) {
        this.sidcname = value;
    }

    public String getSidc() {
        return sidc;
    }

    public void setSidc(String value) {
        this.sidc = value;
    }
}
```

**Step 4: Trying to unmarshal**

```
File file = new File("//main//resources//tacticalSymbols.xml"); 
        JAXBContext context;
        try {
            context = JAXBContext.newInstance(CorpsSymbol.class);

            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

            CorpsSymbol symbols = (CorpsSymbol) unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

            System.out.println(symbols.getName());
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Here, the unmarshalling is giving an exception 
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.net.UnknownHostException: main]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:246)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:162)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:171)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:189)

**I am not able to understand, where exactly is the problem.**

Comment: Remove the doctype declaration (the line with `<!DOCTYPE ...>`) from your XML.

Comment: Done. Still the same issue

Comment: Do you recall if you ever figured out the problem?  I am encountering something similar at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to make sure that the problem isn't in the file path? Namely this line:

```
File file = new File("//main//resources//tacticalSymbols.xml");
```

Try this instead

```
File file = new File("tacticalSymbols.xml");
```